[Google Cloud Platform]: Service Account - Unable to be gracefully shutdown/terminate a project due to the Permissions Rights
I'm having some trouble/problem trying to gracefully shutdown/terminate some project that I've created in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) as a way to try out some virtual deployment, in order to learn and familiarize with deploying some projects on GCP.
I've raised this issue with Google Technical Support - and at this point of writing - we are still not able to resolve the issue. And therefore I am opening out this issue to StakeOverFlow in order to find out how this issue can be resolved.
Some of the attempt that I've made:

shutdown the project via GCP Setting (not achievable/do-able)
using the google cloud platform command line interface (CLI) - gcloud projects delete PROJECT_ID_OR_NUMBER (and I received the following message..)

Error Message:
Troubleshooting info:
Principal: user@email.com
Resource: corvid-managed-0cad0662
Troubleshooting URL: console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter;permissions=iam.serviceAccounts.create;principal=user@gmail.com;resources=%2F%2Fcloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com%2Fprojects%2Fcorvid-managed-0cad0662/result
Missing permissions:
iam.serviceAccounts.create
**What did I try: **
I've tried two methods:

I tried to shutdown the project gracefully via the Graphic User Interface (GUI), on the project setting. But the shutdown button is not usable/not enabled.
I've tried to use the Google CLI command - gcloud projects delete PROJECT_ID_OR_NUMBER but I get some error message:-


Troubleshooting info:
Principal: user@gmail.com
Resource: corvid-managed-8888888888888888
Troubleshooting URL: console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter;permissions=iam.serviceAccounts.create;principal=user@gmail.com;resources=%2F%2Fcloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com%2Fprojects%2Fcorvid-managed-8888888888888888/result
Missing permissions:
iam.serviceAccounts.create
What were I expecting
I believe that there are some permission rights conflicting issues that result in me not being able to shutdown the project gracefully.
I have tried to use the Google CLIs - thinking that it might be a way to delete the associated project, but to no avail - this is not working either.

Action Taken:
I've raised this issue with Google Cloud Technical Support - and as of this point of writing, they are not able to provide a resolution to this issue as well. They have mentioned that they will need some time to look into the issue, and therefore I've provided the project ID for them to check once again.
There should not be any associated dependencies - e.g the ownership of this project belonging to someone else (or another email address).

This project does not belong to any organisation. Or rather this project is not a child of any organisation.
